# Microscope Images with overlays in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, proj4js

I am trying to build an viewer based on OpenLayers to view microscope images with overlays.

The images are > 50000 px x 50000 px and show a region of ~ 100 mm x 100 mm. In addition to the images, I have shapefiles with vector data I want to use as overlays.

So far I managed to convert the images to XYZ images stacks with pyvips and load the images in OpenLayers. I also have converted the shapefiles with geopandas to GeoJSON files and can use them to overlay the microscope image. 
 However, I was not able to define such a projection with proj4js for the map or the GeoJSON file to fit them both together.
I already calculated the affine transformation matrix for the images to overlay the shapefile vector data based on the pixel value and coordinates in mm.

**Is it possible to use no projection at all and just use pixel coordinates?

Or to define a projection based on an affine transformation matrix?**

[Schematic microscope image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZeHy.png) 
[Schematic vector data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RM1Sn.png) 
[Schematic transformed microscope image with vector data overlay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nu6m3.png)

Comment: I think you should be able to use a pixel coordinate system throughout, as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/static-image.html